# What is the valid range for program return value in Linux/bash?

Tags: c, bash, return-value, ubuntu-10.04

I have a C program which returns an integer value. I was surprised to find out that when examining the return value from the shell prompt I get the value modulo 256.

```
/* prog.c */
int main(...) { return 257; }
```

--

```
> ./prog.e
> echo $?  
1
```

- Why don't I see the whole integer?
- Where is this behavior documented?
- How can I get the whole 32-bit value to the shell?

Comment: Return values are by definition error codes. You cannot use the return value to communicate some other numeric value, it is *necessarily* used to indicate success (0) or an error (non-zero). If your intent is to output some kind of count or other non-zero numeric value during a *successful* execution, you must write it to STDOUT.

Comment: Thanks, @meagar. I need this as a temporary hack on some non-production code I work on - to verify my embedded code development. I understand the caveat you mention, but yet, it does not answer my question.

Comment: That is why it is a comment, not an answer. Comments are not *supposed* to answer questions. Temporary hack or otherwise, you aren't going to be able to ahold of the number you're returning. You will have to output it to STDOUT.

Comment: It's not *necessarily* used to indicate success or error.  0 = success, other = faliure is a convention only.

Comment: @meager - yes, after reading the answer posted later, I understood my misfortune.

Comment: @JeremyP A convention used by pretty much every program since before I was born, and that ancient things such as built-in conditionals in shells assume to be true for all programs. I call that a *standard*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> When a program exits, it can return to the parent process a small amount of information about the cause of termination, using the exit status. This is a value between 0 and 255 that the exiting process passes as an argument to exit.

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Exit-Status.html

alternatively:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status

came from "posix return codes" and "c return codes" respective Google searches.

Answer (score 4):

The explanation is right at the top of `man exit`:

```
   The  exit() function causes normal process termination and the value of
   status & 0377 is returned to the parent (see wait(2)).
```

In other words, only the lowest 8 bits are propagated to the parent process.

In this respect, returning the exit code from `main()` is no different to passing it to `exit()`.

Comment: Thanks. I actually looked in the `man bash` page but couldn't find that there. I guess b/c I was doing C I did not think of looking at the `exit` page.

Answer (score 2):

The return status is explained (sort of) in the [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html) and related syscalls.

Basically:

> **WEXITSTATUS(stat_val)**
>   If the value of WIFEXITED(stat_val) is non-zero, this macro evaluates to **the low-order 8 bits of the status argument that the child process passed to _exit() or exit()**, or the value the child process returned from main().

So it's limited to 8 bits. You can't portably get more than that. (With Linux kernel 2.6.9 and above, waitid(2) can be used to obtain the full 32 bits.)

Comment: Is there any way to read full 32b exit code from command started in bash?