# Why does the program return with an exit code other than I specified?

Tags: c, exit-code

This is a simple program :

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The exit code is `0`.

If I write:

```
int main() {
    return 700;
}
```

The exit code is `188`.

Why is `188` instead of `700` the exit code here?

Comment: [What is the valid range for program return value in Linux/bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082953/what-is-the-valid-range-for-program-return-value-in-linux-bash)

Comment: @Mr.Bose "a simple program that shows your current date and time". what do you mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the main function in C returns an `int`, [operating systems don't necessarily use `int` as the error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149228/main-return-value-range).

`700` in binary is `1010111100`.
Truncating this value to eight bits yields `10111100`.
This equals `188` in decimal.

That means your OS uses eight bits for error codes.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> Or possibly nine bits because the 8<sup>th</sup> bit (we start counting from 0, mind you) is `0` here. This is highly improbably due to `9` not being a power of `2`, though, as is convention for data widths.

Comment: Probably 8 bits, I have run into this when automating testing on Linux boxes.

Comment: @tletnes Yes, of course. It was more intended to be theoretical. No sane OS will implement it with 9 bits.