# Capture return value from python

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script `TestNode.sh`. This script has content like this:

```
port_up=$(python TestPorts.py)
python TestRPMs.py
```

Now, I want to capture the value returned by these scripts.

`TestPorts.py`

```
def CheckPorts():
    if PortWorking(8080):
        print "8080 working"
        return "8080"
    elif PortWorking(9090):
        print "9090 working"
        return "9090"
```

But as I checked the answers available, they are not working for me. The `print` is pushing the value in variable `port_up`, but I wanted that `print` should `print` on the console and the variable `port_up` should get the value from return statement. Is there a way to achieve this?

Note: I don't wish to use `sys.exit()`. Is it possible to achieve the same without this?

Answer (score 2):

> but I wanted that print should print on the console and the variable port_up should get the value from return statement.

Then don't capture the *output*. Instead do:

```
python TestPorts.py
port_up=$? # return value of the last statement
python TestRPMs.py
```

---

You could do:

```
def CheckPorts():
    if PortWorking(8080):
        sys.stderr.write("8080 working")
    print 8080
```

But then I am not very happy to print "output" to `stderr` either.

Alternatively, you could skip printing that "8080 working" message in python script and print it from the shell script.

```
def CheckPorts():
    if PortWorking(8080):
        return "8080"
```

and:

```
port_up=$(python TestPorts.py)
echo "$port_up working"
python TestRPMs.py
```

Comment: That just tells whether the script execution was successful or not.

Comment: If you want to use the exit value (to get port num), I don't see another way (shorting of writing to a file or parsing the python script's output etc).

Comment: Hmm, then I have to redesign my solution. Thanks :)

Comment: I have updated with some more suggestions. It's not too tricky to solve this. But it's upto you decide which one you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

To return an exit code from a Python script you can use `sys.exit()`; `exit()` *may* also work. In the Bash (and similar) shell, the exit code of the previous command can be found in `$?`.

However, the Linux shell exit codes are 8 bit unsigned integers, i.e. in the range 0-255, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8083027/4014959). So your strategy isn't going to work.

Perhaps you can print "8080 working" to stderr or a logfile and print "8080" to stdout so you can capture it with `$()`.