# Comparing the outputs between a function and a function template on Compiler Explorer

Tags: c++, gcc, output, c++17, compiler-explorer

I implemented simple versions of the factorial function which both can be seen [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sK6fsY). I'm using GCC Trunk. There are 2 source files, the first being the function version and the second being the templated version. Each source file has 2 attached compilers with an associated output. The only difference between the two attached compilers for each source file is that the lefthand compiler has no compiler flags or optimizations turned on, and the righthand version has `-O3` set to turn on level 3 optimizations.

Here are my functions:

```
// Function Version
int factorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return 1;
    if (n == 2) return 2;
    return (n * factorial(n-1));
}

// Template Version:
template<unsigned N>
static auto constexpr factorial_t() {
    return (N * factorial<N-1>());
}

template<>
auto constexpr factorial_t<0>() {
    return 1;
}
template<>
auto constexpr factorial_t<1>() {
    return 1;
}
template<>
auto constexpr factorial_t<2>() {
    return 2;
}
```

Now, when I run these in my installed `IDE` `Visual Studio 2017` on my local PC using `c++17`, I am getting the expected output returned back from `main()`, and the returned value is correct for both implementations.

I ported this to Compiler Explorer to test other compilers and their optimizations to compare their generated assembly instructions. This is a fairly straightforward process.

Now when I run these functions as such:

**source#1**

```
int main() {
    return factorial(6);
}
```

**source#2**

```
int main() {
    return factorial_t<6>();
}
```

Compiler Explorer generates the following instruction counts...

> - ```
>            |   Assembly Instruction Count   |
>   ```
> - ```
>   Type     | Without O3 | With O3 Turned On |
>   ```
> - ```
>   Function |     34     |       29          |
>   ```
> - ```
>   Template |     50     |        3          |
>   ```

All is good.

All four program executions return a value of `208`.

Now to my question:

However, it's not obvious within the assembly of the first and third compilers directly without doing some register math, but in the second and last with `-O3` turned on for both the `function` and `template` versions, the value `720` is being stored into the `EAX` register before `main()`'s return call. Why is Compiler Explorer displaying: `Program returned: 208` instead of `720`?

Comment: `main` can only return an 8 bit value - 720 % 256 = 208

Comment: @PaulR Oh okay... Yeah, when I was looking at it, I was thinking maybe hex, but 720 in hex is not 208... it didn't dawn on me that `main` was only returning a single byte... yet the `function` declaration of `main()`'s return type is `int` which should be, 16, 32 or 64 bit depending on both architecture and OS... I always assumed `main()`'s return type was an `int`. It never dawned on me to do `modulus` arithmetic...

Comment: Yes, it’s historical, since main only returns a status code I guess people felt that 8 bits were sufficient.

Comment: @PaulR However, if that's the case, then why does it display `720` to the command prompt in Windows 7 on my 64bit machine when I run either version that the program had returned?

Comment: Windows always has to be different. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR Don't get me wrong, I appreciate your feedback on narrowing down this discrepancy... I was just shaking my head there for a while trying to figure out `how`, `where`, and `why` this value was being generated...

Comment: @PaulR So I'm guessing because `C++` standard allows specific things within the language to be `implementation-defined` from one compiler to another and from one OS to another... this may then come down to `calling conventions` and how each compiler treats `main()` with respect to both the architecture and OS it is used on...

Comment: @PaulR I think this might lead to another `Q/A`...

Comment: `main` does return `int`, but the C++ standard doesn't say how many bits of it will be used by OS. Now, POSIX does use only 8 bits (Windows uses 32 bits), see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149228/return-value-range-of-the-main-function

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8082953/253056

Comment: @heapunderrun When I switched Compiler Explorer to use `MSVC x64 latest`... with -O2 set... It was returning 0... so this was giving me the assumption that `720 mod` `2^32` will equal `0` as there is no remainder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) is defined to return an `int`. After `main` returns the c++ runtime will call `std::exit` (or equivalent code) with the value returned from `main`.

[`std::exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) also takes an `int` exit code. How this exit code is turned into a process return code is implementation defined.

On Unix the return code for a process is usually a single unsigned byte so the `int` is simply truncated to fit into `0` - `255`.

On Windows process return codes are 32-bit signed integers so the `int` value passed to `std::exit` is returned directly.

Comment: Not realizing that `main()` only returns `8-bits` on `GCC` or `Clang` as opposed to `MSVC` for `Windows`, I guess this is coming from the lack of using `Linux` or other `POSIX` `Unix` - `BSD` derived Operating Systems... 95% of the time I'm using Windows specifically for my desktop. The only variants of POSIX I may use would be from devices such as some phones `Android` and TV Device boxes such as `Roku`, `Kodi` like devices, and Amazon's `FireTV` sticks or boxes, and Smart TVs... However, I don't do much programming on them, I just use their interfaces to use them...

Comment: @FrancisCugler `main` always returns an `int`, how that is translated into a process return code is platform specific (not compiler specific, e.g. if you use clang or gcc on windows you'll probably get 32-bit exit codes)

Comment: True... that makes complete sense since this would come down to the operating system's syscalls...